# How to add dynamic values in between words in a sentence using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Description: Say I have to show a details like below

> *Showing 3 of 10 records.*

Here literal part comes from a authoring mechanism and numbers are dynamic. Now instead of receiving three properties like below and concatenate them, is there any ready-made way to do this in javascript receiving single property?

```
{
  text1: "Showing",
  text2: "of",
  text3: "records.",
}
```

**Possible Solution:** We can use a separator in the sentence and fetch that in single property and then split the sentence and use. Also we can replace that by dynamic data.

Is this solution is correct or there are better ways to do that?

Comment: How about having some placeholder? You would receive something like `text = "Showing {0} of {1} records"` with a convention that you always receive in an array _recordsCount_ the _count_ before the _total_. Then (sorry for ugly text), you can replace each placeholder: `for (let i = 0; i < _recordsCount_.length; i++) { text = text.replace(``{${i}}``, args[i]); } ` (I need to double the backtick to display it)

Comment: @Al-un, thank you. That's what I mentioned in possible solutions. I was searching if there is any readymade solution.

Comment: my bad then I misunderstood your _Possible Solution_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best possible solution is to use placeholder/separators. Thanks @Al-un for your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is next

```
const number = 3
const total = 10    
const output = `Showing ${number} of ${total} records`
```

More info about template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: This won't solve my issue. My target was not to receive 'Showing', 'of', 'records' this texts in separate JSON properties.